# AngularJS + Protractor wait for all ajax calls to end / full page load, before running the tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Is there a better way to wait until all page is loaded,

my angular pages are loaded with promise, it means that if all ajaxs call haven't ended yet
there is a loader on the screen.

i'm currently using  ptor.sleep(10000), like in the following example:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    driver = ptor.driver;
    ptor.get(base_url);
    ptor.sleep(10000);
});
```

is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Found the answer for this in the answer for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808463/what-is-browser-ignoresynchronization-in-protractor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `ng-if` to hide/show your content when loading starts/finishes, you can use the following syntax to wait until a certain element appears on the page (i.e. `ng-if` will prevent the element from being in the DOM until the page finishes loading):

```
ptor.findElement(by.id('element-only-shown-after-loading')).then(function (myElement) {
    // Your page should be loaded at this point
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why this works, if the element is not in the DOM shouldn't `findElement` be unable to find it?

Comment: ptor.findElement() waits until it finds that element to resolve it's promise. So you can wait passively until that element appears on the page and then run your code.