# Using Page Object Pattern Correctly in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have an `Angular` app and I am using `Protractor` to test it.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="all" class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="dashboard-stat block panel padder-v bg-primary">
            <div class="icon hidden-xs">
              <img src="../assets/images/icon-ppt-inv.png">
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="value" class="font-thin h1 block">
                {{summary.num | number:0}}
              </div>
              <div id="name" class="text-muted text-xs">
                Albert
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**Here is the code for the Page Object:**

```
    'use strict';

        var history_page = function (){

            this.getStat = function(){
                return element.all(by.css('#all'));
            };

            this.getName = function(){
                return element(by.css('#name')).getText();
            };

            this.getValue = function(){
                return element(by.css('#value')).getText();
            };


        };

        module.exports = new history_page();
```

**Test Code**

```
 var historyPage = require('./history_page.js');

    it('Test', function(){


     var history = historyPage.getStat().map(function (stat) {
        return {
            name: stat.historyPage.getName()
            value: stat.historyPage.getValue(),
        }
    });

     history.then(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
    });


     });
```

For some reason I keep getting an error saying *getName* is not defined. If I change the following two lines

```
name: stat.historyPage.getName() 
value: stat.historyPage.getValue(),
```

as

```
name: stat.element(by.css('#name')).getText(),
value: stat.element(by.css('#value')).getText()
```

It works fine. I am not sure what the reason is. I really want to avoid writing css locators on my test page as it does not look good and it is a bad practice. I will appreciate suggestions to help me.

Comment: This does not directly answer your question, but I recommend the astrolabe framework for page objects.  In my opinion, it will make things easier for you.

Comment: Is it possible to show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the complete `map()` block into the Page Object:

```
var history_page = function () {
    this.all = element.all(by.css('#all'));

    this.getStat = function() {
        return this.all.map(function (stat) {
            return {
                name: stat.element(by.css('#name')).getText(),
                value: stat.element(by.css('#value')).getText()
            }
        });
    };
};

module.exports = new history_page();
```

Comment: So then what would my test look like?This means if i have 3 maps then i move all 3 inside page object?

Comment: @Dinero your test would use this `getStat()` function that resolves into an array of objects. What other maps do you have? Thanks.

Comment: I would have something similar where name: stat.element(by.css('#name1')).getText(),
                value: stat.element(by.css('#value1')).getText()

I have about 5 such maps possibly.

Comment: @Dinero are they all related to the same history page and all can be located under the `#all`?

Comment: @Dinero what if you have `all` as separate field inside the page object, please see the update.

Comment: I do not see the update. I was just wondering what would happen for my other ones where I have name: stat.element(by.css('#name1')).getText(), value: stat.element(by.css('#value1')).getText()  
etc.. So would each one be moved inside page object?

Comment: @Dinero the update was to move the `element.all(by.css('#all'))` into a separate `this.all` field. Yeah, I think you should first try to move all of your maps under page object. Please post the code once you do it and we'll see what we can do to improve. Thanks.

Comment: Sure I will do that right now @ alecxe, thanks for the great suggestions. Also i was wondering if it is possible to write a npm script that will start up the webdriver-manager server everytime ? I am posting it as a different question maybe you know already.

Comment: @Dinero for local testing purposes use `chromeOnly` to control chrome driver directly. Aside from that, use `grunt` to start up a web-server, selenium server and run protractor tests.

Comment: I have yet another issue with protractor maybe you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013683/getting-the-angular-content-to-load-in-protractor-tests

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

    var history_page = function (){

        this.getStat = function(){
            return element.all(by.css('#all'));
        };

        this.getName = function(index){
            return this.getStat().then(function(stats){
                  return stats[index].get(index).element(by.css('#name'));
        };


    };

    module.exports = new history_page();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, locators, functions (like @alecxe mentions), and conditions belong in the page object. Otherwise it defeats the purpose of them.

I would do something like:

```
var historyPage = function() {
    this.stats = $$('.row');
    this.name = $('#name');
    this.getValue = $('#value');
};
module.exports = new history_page();
```

And the test to be something like:

```
var historyPage = require('./history_page.js');

it('Test', function() {
    expect(historyPage.name.getText()).toBe('Albert');
});
```

Using a map for repeated data is cool... but in your example, I'm not sure I follow. `#all` would be unique, so if you're going to map repeated data, you'd probably want to map off of `.row`? Not sure. But it might look something like this:

```
    this.getStat = function() {
        var that = this;
        return this.stats.map(function(stat) {
            return {
                // not tested... 
                name: stat.that.name.getText(),
                value: stat.that.value.getText()
            }
        });
    };
```

And FWIW, I have some page object examples in my [protractor_example repo](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example)