# Getting the Angular Content to load in protractor tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor, saucelabs

I have an angular application that I am writing e2e test for using protractor.

Following is my conf.js file setup

```
var project = require('./package.json');
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

var multiCapabilities = [{
    'browserName': 'chrome'
}];

multiCapabilities = [{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    "platform": "Windows 7",
    'build': 'Testing',
    'name': project.name + ' tests'
}]

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    sauceUser: 'blahblhablah',
    sauceKey: 'xyzabcdxyzabac',
    multiCapabilities: multiCapabilities,
    specs: ['e2e/main.spec.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },
    onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            dest: 'reports/e2e'
        }));
    }
};
```

Following is my test spec file

```
'use strict';

var mainPage = require('./page.js');
describe('Demo', function() {

    //Check if title pages are consistent
    it('Test 1', function() {

        browser.get('http://localhost:3000/'); 
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('NBA LIVE');
    });
});
```

I am running my test on saucelabs when I run them locally I have no issues. So after I ran this test I got the following error message.

> Message:
>         Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:3000/ : retries looking for
>         angular exceeded

So i did a little more research and realized I can set  `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` in my test spec file.

So after doing that I get the following error message:

> Message:
>         Expected 'http://localhost:3000/' to equal 'NBA LIVE'.

So I think maybe the angular or the content is not loading because of me setting ignoring synchronization to true but if i do not then I get the other error. Again none of this is an issue when running my test locally on my laptop but only when doing on saucelab. It is clear I need to add something to make angular content load. Please advice me on what to do.

Comment: But what do you see on the screenshot (s)? Do you see your app loaded? Thanks.

Comment: screenshots of saucelabs do you mean ?

Comment: Yeah, I think they have test sessions recorded with logs and screenshots.

Comment: Hi @alecxe, thank you for your help i have another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053979/css-is-messed-up-while-running-protractor-on-saucelabs  (you might know this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what might be happening is that it's checking the expect before the page loads so you could try to make it wait till the title says NBA LIVE before you expect it by using the [protractor.until](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-protractor/angular-protractor-tests.ts#L172) statments

```
    browser.wait(protractor.until.titleIs("NBA LIVE"), 5000, "✗ Failed to wait for the NBA LIVE page to load");
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual("NBA LIVE");
```

**EDIT:**

Since you are using a local app and using saucelabs then you will need to setup [sauce connect](https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/sauce-connect/)

Comment: It failed to wait and timedout.

Comment: so if you just manually go to this address via your browser in the actual title bar of the browser does it show NBA LIVE? does it show the same in sauce labs?

Comment: yes it does @BarretV, also keep in mind that i am running this on Saucelabs so It does not matter what is happening on my local laptop, i think the app is loaded on saucelab servers.

Comment: do you have a tunnel running for saucelabs since this is a local app. The documentation for that is here https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/sauce-connect/

Comment: you are correct !! I needed to setup sauce-connect, please update your answer so i can accept it and give you credit.

Comment: please update your answer with saucelab connect :) thanks again i want to accept your answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer and I'm glad to hear I was able to help out

Comment: Hey, I have yet another question you might be able to help me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053979/css-is-messed-up-while-running-protractor-on-saucelabs