# Configure saucelabs for jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, protractor, saucelabs

I am trying to run my protractor tests on my Jenkins server which happens to be a Linux box (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6) which has no browser. So i did some research and realized I would have to use saucelabs. I do have saucelab account. So i was confused on how to edit my conf.js file and also how i will communicate with saucelabs from my box.

This is my current conf.js file

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

var reporter=new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: './result', 
    docTitle: Result',
    docName:    'report.html'
});

exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: ['spec.js'],

  onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
    },

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
}
```

My understanding is I have to add my username and access key for saucelabs as such

```
export SAUCE_USERNAME=YOUR_USERNAME

export SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
```

I was wondering how exactly it will go in my conf.js file and also MOST IMPORTANT, HOW will my linux box be communicating with sauce labs???? Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/spec/ciFullConf.js#L5) protractor provides to help you run your tests on Saucelabs.

Most importantly, you need to specify the `sauceUser` and `sauceKey` to make it work:

```
exports.config = {
  sauceUser: "user",
  sauceKey: "key",

  // ...

}
```

Comment: is that all that is required? how will Jenkins server communicate with saucelabs?

Comment: @Dinero basically yes, there is a [Sauce driver provider](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/e996a90644a7d2966636dd718e279fb9dc8753f9/lib/runner.js#L87) built into protractor.

Comment: i thought you also need some tunnel identifier ?

Comment: @Dinero got it. You are right, from what I understand (we are using browserstack so I could be wrong), you need to start up a sauce tunnel. For instance, via grunt and [`grunt-sauce-tunnel`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sauce-tunnel).

Comment: also i am a little confused because I am doing this on jenkins. When i do it locally i usually fire up my application on local host and in my spec i do browser.get(localhost:myport). On jenkins how will all this work ? Because in reality my application has not started or anything it is just build.

Comment: @Dinero I see what you mean. Aside from firing up a tunnel, you also need to fire up a *local web server*, via, for instance, [`grunt-contrib-connect`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect). So, to summarize, you'll have a grunt task with: `connect`, `sauce-connect`, `protractor`. Hope that clear things up.

Comment: @Dinero I'll add all of these to the answer, once we'll make it work for you.

Comment: i am using gulp serve to start my application not grunt so does that still apply?

Comment: @Dinero yes, the idea would be still the same: start up a local web server, give sauce access to it via a tunnel, run tests against your app running on a local web server.

Comment: i am confused as there is no browser though on this box. Also i would imagine we would need way to shutdown test after it is done also right.

Comment: is it possible to join chat

Comment: would you happen to know solution to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567894/fail-pipeline-in-jenkins