# Protractor isDisplayed incorrectly returns false for visible element

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, protractor

I have a bootstrap "loading" alert message which I display conditionally using ng-show, while the results of an API call are being loaded after a button click.

The markup is:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" data-ng-show="loading" id="a-message">
    loading...
</div>
```

The protractor code is:

```
expect(element(by.id('a-message')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true); // returns true
element(by.id('fetch-data')).click(); // The click handler sets $scope.loading = true, and the loading message becomes visible

browser.wait(function () {
        return element(by.id('a-message')).isDisplayed().then(function (displayed) {
            return displayed;
        });
    }, 10000);
expect(element(by.id('a-message')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Once the loading is completed, $scope.loading is set back to false; 
I can see the loading message appear and then disappear, but the console log is always false.

My questions are:

1. Is this possible to test? I.e. is Protractor able to test the visibility of the loading message while the page is waiting for an API call to return data in the background?
2. If this is possible to test, what am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've been playing with the code, by adding debug statements, and it seems, protractor waits for the API call (triggered by the click()) to complete in the background before proceeding to the next line (browser.wait). As a result, protractor never gets to see the "Loading" div. Is there a way to prevent protractor from waiting for the API call to complete?

Comment: Found the answer to this in the answer for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808463/what-is-browser-ignoresynchronization-in-protractor