# Running protractor test on safari, say "Angular could not be found on the page https://angularjs.org/"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, safari, protractor

I try to run protractor test on Safari, but I have a problem even with an official example (http://www.protractortest.org/ I attach below my conf.js and todo-spec.js files).

When I set browser.ignoreSynchronization=true; ([What is browser.ignoreSynchronization in protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808463/what-is-browser-ignoresynchronization-in-protractor)) then test works, but I can not take advantage of protractor.

https://angularjs.org/ uses angular 1.6.4

---

- log from run test:

  ```
  $ node ./node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js conf.js --browser safari
  (node:5778) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
  [09:49:28] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://MAC_IP:4444/wd/hub
  [09:49:28] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
  Started
  [09:49:41] E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page https://angularjs.org/ : angular never provided resumeBootstrap
  F

  Failures:
  1) angularjs homepage todo list should add a todo
    Message:
      Failed: Angular could not be found on the page https://angularjs.org/. If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load
    Stack:
      Error: Angular could not be found on the page https://angularjs.org/. If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load
          at /home/tester/proj/js/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:506:23
          at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/home/tester/proj/js/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
          at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/tester/proj/js/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
          at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/tester/proj/js/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
          at asyncRun (/home/tester/proj/js/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27)
          at /home/tester/proj/js/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
      From: Task: Run it("should add a todo") in control flow
          at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tester/proj/js/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:79:14)
      From asynchronous test: 
      Error
          at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/tester/proj/js/todo-spec.js:2:3)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tester/proj/js/todo-spec.js:1:1)
          at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
          at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
          at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
          at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)

  1 spec, 1 failure
  Finished in 11.68 seconds
  [09:49:41] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
  [09:49:41] I/launcher - safari #01 failed 1 test(s)
  [09:49:41] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
  [09:49:41] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
  ```

---

- webdriver-manager start logs:

  ```
  $  ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start
  [09:49:21] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/tester/proj/js/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.29 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/Users/tester/proj/js/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.15.0 -jar /Users/tester/proj/js/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -port 4444
  [09:49:21] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 95779
  09:49:21.673 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32'
  09:49:21.673 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
  2017-04-12 09:49:21.724:INFO::main: Logging initialized @358ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
  09:49:21.777 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
   registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
  09:49:21.777 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
   registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
  09:49:21.777 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
  09:49:21.777 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
  Unable to create new instances on this machine.
  09:49:21.778 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
  09:49:21.778 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
  2017-04-12 09:49:21.823:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.20.v20161216
  2017-04-12 09:49:21.849:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5c3bd550{/,null,AVAILABLE}
  2017-04-12 09:49:21.880:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1ce92674{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
  2017-04-12 09:49:21.881:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @515ms
  09:49:21.881 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
  09:49:28.191 INFO - SessionCleaner initialized with insideBrowserTimeout 0 and clientGoneTimeout 1800000 polling every 180000
  09:49:28.214 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=safari}]])
  09:49:28.235 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=safari}]
  09:49:29.500 INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
  09:49:29.515 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=safari}]]
  09:49:29.533 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 11000])
  09:49:29.541 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 11000]
  09:49:29.715 INFO - Executing: [get: about:blank])
  09:49:29.954 INFO - Done: [get: about:blank]
  09:49:29.964 INFO - Executing: [execute script: window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!" + window.name;window.location.replace("https://angularjs.org/");, []])
  09:49:29.994 INFO - Done: [execute script: window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!" + window.name;window.location.replace("https://angularjs.org/");, []]
  09:49:30.005 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.040 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.049 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.054 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.064 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.090 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.102 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.107 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.120 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.141 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.149 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.154 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.161 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.191 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.199 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.204 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.212 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.241 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.250 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.256 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.273 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.442 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.451 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.455 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.475 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.492 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.500 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.505 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.512 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.543 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.549 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.553 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.560 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.591 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.600 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.604 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.610 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.647 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.653 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.657 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.662 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.698 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.704 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.742 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.750 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.754 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.761 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.797 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.803 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.844 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.851 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.856 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.863 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.897 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.903 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.908 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.915 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.946 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:30.956 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:30.996 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:31.002 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:31.006 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:31.013 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
  09:49:31.056 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
  09:49:31.062 INFO - Executing: [execute async script: try { return (function (attempts, ng12Hybrid, asyncCallback) {
    var callback = function(args) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        asyncCallback(args);
      }, 0);
    };
    var check = function(n) {
      try {
        if (!ng12Hybrid && window.getAllAngularTestabilities) {
          callback({ver: 2});
        } else if (window.angular && window.angular.resumeBootstrap) {
          callback({ver: 1});
        } else if (n < 1) {
          if (window.angular) {
            callback({message: 'angular never provided resumeBootstrap'});
          } else {
            callback({message: 'retries looking for angular exceeded'});
          }
        } else {
          window.setTimeout(function() {check(n - 1);}, 1000);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        callback({message: e});
      }
    };
    check(attempts);
  }).apply(this, arguments); }
  catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, [10, false]])
  09:49:41.340 INFO - Done: [execute async script: try { return (function (attempts, ng12Hybrid, asyncCallback) {
    var callback = function(args) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        asyncCallback(args);
      }, 0);
    };
    var check = function(n) {
      try {
        if (!ng12Hybrid && window.getAllAngularTestabilities) {
          callback({ver: 2});
        } else if (window.angular && window.angular.resumeBootstrap) {
          callback({ver: 1});
        } else if (n < 1) {
          if (window.angular) {
            callback({message: 'angular never provided resumeBootstrap'});
          } else {
            callback({message: 'retries looking for angular exceeded'});
          }
        } else {
          window.setTimeout(function() {check(n - 1);}, 1000);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        callback({message: e});
      }
    };
    check(attempts);
  }).apply(this, arguments); }
  catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, [10, false]]
  09:49:41.351 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 199560b8-0691-456f-927e-15991a47acea])
  09:49:41.446 INFO - Done: [delete session: 199560b8-0691-456f-927e-15991a47acea]
  ```

---

- conf.js:

  ```
  exports.config = {
      framework: 'jasmine2',
      seleniumAddress: 'http://MAC_IP:4444/wd/hub',
      specs: ['todo-spec.js']
  };
  ```
- todo-spec.js:

  ```
  describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
    it('should add a todo', function() {
      browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

      element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
      element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

      var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
      expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
      expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

      // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
      todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
      var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
      expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
    });
  });
  ```

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using?
Setting `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true` will tell protractor not to wait for Angular to finish loading the page / Angular content. By default protractor will ask Angular if it is done loading the needed data / processes.

Comment: Safari 10.1 (11603.1.30.0.34)

Answer (score 0):

I know there are some issues with async stuff in Safari 10, see also [this comment](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2840#issuecomment-290452927) in the protractor git. It describes a workaround for Safari Desktop.

Hope it helps / gives you enough info.

Comment: This brings the same effect as ignoreSynchronization. I would need to hook into some event or something similar...