# Protractor timeout with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm currently struggling with `e2e` tests using `Protractor` and `Angularjs`. I've used the test project here: https://github.com/mbcooper/ProtractorExample.

Unfortunately, Protractor fails 4 of the tests complaining about a `timeout` in Angularjs code.

Here's the output of one of the failed tests:

```
Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 
seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular 
application. 
Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, *[id="searchButton"]). 
The following tasks were pending:
 - $timeout: function (){X(k);k=[]}
```

Here's a full log at pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/5DhDDRGb

I'd appreciate any help here.

Comment: Increase the timeout by using allScriptsTimeout to a bigger value. Refer to the link in the error...

Comment: I agree with @Grasshopper. Can you also paste some of your testcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

before you open your browser. To read more about this, you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808463/what-is-browser-ignoresynchronization-in-protractor).