# What is difference between waitForAngularEnabled and browser.ignoreSynchronization in protractor?

Tags: protractor

What is browser.ignoreSynchronization?

```
/**
   * If true, Protractor will not attempt to synchronize with the page before
   * performing actions. This can be harmful because Protractor will not wait
   * until $timeouts and $http calls have been processed, which can cause
   * tests to become flaky. This should be used only when necessary, such as
   * when a page continuously polls an API using $timeout.
   *
   * @type {boolean}
   */
```

&
[waitForAngularEnabled](http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts#how-to-disable-waiting-for-angular)
Both looks same. Is there any specific thing that can achieve by one and not by other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are the exact same, if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/browser.ts#L225) `ignoreSynchronization` actually calls `waitForAngularEnabled`.  The only thing to note is, `ignoreSynchronization` is being deprecated and eventually will no longer be available.  They are switching to `waitForAngularEnabled` as the main property.

As far as what they do, that has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808463/what-is-browser-ignoresynchronization-in-protractor) in good detail.