# How to solve the error: Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page

Tags: angular, webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I have an e2e testing using protractor. My test involves angular page and non-angular page. I have no problem to test on non-angular page. But I have an error when the test finished on the non-angular page and back to angular page.

My test starts from a home page(angular page) and click login button. This will redirect to a non-angular page. Finish typing username and password, then redirect to angular page again. I have issue on the last step when test back to angular page.

```
beforeAll(() => {
    page = new Abcflow();
});

fdescribe('step 1', () => {
   beforeEach(async () => await page.navigateToStart());

    fit('login as staff and come back to home page', async () => {
    //start from an angular page
    await page.clickButton('a', 'Login / Register');

    //now in a non-angular page
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Email')).sendKeys('email');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Password')).sendKeys('password');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('button')).click();

    //navigate back to angular page
    await page.navigateToStart();

    expect(await page.getPageTitleText()).toEqual('abc title');
  });
});
```

I can see my test page came back from non-angular page to the angular page. Then I got error like

- Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test
  involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2643 for details"

I have tried to add the lines:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Then I got another error said "No element found using locator". The funny thing is if I don't test the login page and just go for the last line, it will pass successfully. Seems like the angular page tests stopped working after navigating from non-angular page.

Comment: so, the error is right. 1) You could add `await browser.sleep(5000)` before lines with some actions 2) please add `HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

You got:

```
No element found using locator
```

Because Protractor didn't wait for page completely loaded and began to search for elements. Synchronization was disabled so you need to add specific time to wait until page loads up:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.sleep(3000);
```

`ignoreSynchronization=true` is used for non-Angular pages or when Protractor is unable to recognize it as Angular page. By default Protractor uses `ignoreSynchronization=false`  and waits for Angular site to be completely loaded.

Also you shouldn't use both `ignoreSynchronization` and `waitForAngularEnabled` in the same time because they do the same thing ([What is difference between waitForAngularEnabled and browser.ignoreSynchronization in protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321799/what-is-difference-between-waitforangularenabled-and-browser-ignoresynchronizati?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Answer (score 1):

If your code is working as you say it may just be a case of adding the browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

```
fdescribe('step 1', () => {
   beforeEach(async () => await page.navigateToStart());

    fit('login as staff and come back to home page', async () => {
    //start from an angular page
    await page.clickButton('a', 'Login / Register');

    //now in a non-angular page
    await browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Email')).sendKeys('email');
    await browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Password')).sendKeys('password');
    await browser.driver.findElement(by.name('button')).click();

    //Setting this before you navigate back to the Angular page will ensure it will wait 
    // wait for page to load correctly
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

    //navigate back to angular page
    await page.navigateToStart();

    expect(await page.getPageTitleText()).toEqual('abc title');
  });
});
```

That error you are receiving may be a genuine error and an issue with your locator on the angular page but you would need to post your error message and some of your html.

Comment: Thanks @DublinDev . I added the browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); to the exactly line you suggested. Turns out the same error message "Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page:" still happening, but even before it can reach the non-angular page. I'm very confused here now.

Comment: There were some missing await statements before my original suggestion. Please check again and let me know.

Comment: Thank you @DublinDev I found I need both "await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);" and "await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);" in my code to make it work. Thank you for the tips!