# Where can I put the browser.ignoreSynchronization in my config file of protractor?

Tags: protractor

How and where can I put the `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;` in the config file of protractor?

Comment: It doesn't go in the config file, it's a property on the browser object you can access in your tests: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28808463/3001761

Comment: It's true that it is a property on the browser object but if your whole system under test in non-angular you should put it in the onPrepare in the config. Note though that `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true` is deprecated and you should instead use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`